# blend mode for pgf does not work any more

Tags: tikz-pgf

The blend mode for pgf does not work anymore for me? any wisdom from anyone?

It will generate a blank page in the following MWE. But if I remove `blend group=screen`, it will produce a graph without color blending.  I am using Arch linux and the latest version of all the Tex packages.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[blend group=screen]
  \fill[red!90!black]   ( 90:.6) circle (1);
  \fill[green!80!black] (210:.6) circle (1);
  \fill[blue!90!black] (330:.6) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You seem to have two `[` before `blend group=screen` (maybe introduced by the edit). If you use `\begin{tikzpicture}[blend group=screen]` it seems to work, at least on my TeXLive2020 installation when compiled with `pdflatex`.

Comment: Works for me too, after removing the superfluous `[`

Comment: @abcdefg The ```[``` was somehow introduced by edit. It failed when compiled with xelatex.  It WORKS with pdflatex.

Comment: The filling area is wrongly shifted, see https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/928. For a short-term workaround before next release of `pgf`, see the first code example in [this comment](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/928#issuecomment-700690532).